Get SUMPRODUCT with multiple column and row criterias if table includes values that are not numeric


In cell I5 I extract the sum from the table based on multiple column and row criteria using this formula:  =SUMPRODUCT(IF(I3="";1;(A3:A8=I3))*IF(I4="";1;(B3:B8=I4))*IF(I1="";1;(C1:G1=I1))*IF(I2="";1;(C2:G2=I2))*(C3:G8))

This formula has worked until I inserted the Column D. Now I am getting error #VALUE! as result. 
I guess this comes from the situation that Column D does not contain numeric data.
Therefore, I was thinking maybe a formula like this could solve the issue:
=SUMIF(A1:A8;I3;INDEX(A1:G1;MATCH(I1;A1:G1;0)))

However, with this formula I have the problem that I can only apply one row and column criteria and not multiple ones.
Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Do some research over the forum, such type of questions are resolved multiple times. adding an IFERROR() resolves the problem, also I am not sure why you need the column C and D when the conditional columns are based on E-->G --> =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((A3:A8=I3)*IF(I4="",1,(B3:B8=I4))*(C1:G1=I1)*(C2:G2=I2)*(C3:G8),0)) and if you are pertinent in using INDEX() and MATCH() to make more iterations then could try using : =SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(C3:G8,,XMATCH(1,(C1:G1=I1)*(I2=C2:G2)))*(A3:A8=I3)*IF(I4="",1,(B3:B8=I4)))

As already mentioned in the comments below the question. This formula solves the issue:
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IF(I3="";1;(A3:A8=I3))*IF(I4="";1;(B3:B8=I4))*IF(I1="";1;(C1:G1=I1))*IF(I2="";1;(C2:G2=I2))*(C3:G8);0))

The LAMBDA formula in the other answer also solves the issue if it is modified as described in the comments below the answer:
=LET(z;LAMBDA(x;y;IF(x="";1;y=x));SUM(IFERROR(z(I1;C1:G1)*z(I2;C2:G2)*z(I3;A3:A8)*z(I4;B3:B8)*C3:G8;0)))


Since you repeatedly want to use the same logic (if cell value is empty, take all range values, else take only the range values that equal the cell value), we can use that as a LAMBDA:
=LET(z,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(x="",1,y=x)),SUM(z(G1,C1:E1)*z(G2,C2:E2)*z(G3,A3:A8)*z(G4,B3:B8)*C3:E8))
z being the function, x being the cell value, y being the range.
If we than write z(G1,C1:E1) it really means: IF(G1="",1,C1:E1=G1)
This requires you to have Office 365.
Else you should write it all out:
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(G1="",1,C1:E1=G1)*IF(G2="",1,C2:E2=G2)*IF(G3="",1,A3:A8=G3)*IF(G4="",1,B3:B8=G4)*C3:E8)
As Mayukh posted the formulas above both will fail if the sum range contains text. As presented in the images below:

adding headers does not effect the formula


adding text within the sum range does effect the formula



Workaround is to wrap it in IFERROR inside the sum(product) (also credits to Mayukh for the workaround):
=LET(z,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(x="",1,y=x)),SUM(IFERROR(z(I1,C1:E1)*z(I2,C2:E2)*z(I3,A3:A8)*z(I4,B3:B8)*C3:E8,0)))
and
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IF(I3="",1,(A3:A8=I3))*IF(I4="",1,(B3:B8=I4))*IF(I1="",1,(C1:G1=I1))*IF(I2="",1,(C2:G2=I2))*(C3:G8),0))
Note that including the initial and test column's data, would mean the initial data would by included in the sum if you omit the Quarter value. If that's not required, than my first formula can still be used and simply don't include these column's data in the sum range/header range.

This one will return error, needs to wrap within IFERROR() --> =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IF(I3="",1,(A3:A8=I3))*IF(I4="",1,(B3:B8=I4))*IF(I1="",1,(C1:G1=I1))*IF(I2="",1,(C2:G2=I2))*(C3:G8),0)) matrix product of number and text will return error. --> {0,#VALUE!,500,0,0;0,#VALUE!,100,0,0;0,#VALUE!,800,0,0;0,#VALUE!,0,0,0;0,#VALUE!,0,0,0;0,#VALUE!,0,0,0} and even LAMBDA() needs an IFERROR() wrapping: =LET(z,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(x="",1,y=x)),SUM(IFERROR(z(I1,C1:E1)*z(I2,C2:E2)*z(I3,A3:A8)*z(I4,B3:B8)*C3:E8,0)))

It works with my file. Did I miss something about text/numbers?

Column I is the conditional range

I see I skipped the part about "This formula has worked until I inserted the Column D. Now I am getting error #VALUE! as result.
I guess this comes from the situation that Column D does not contain numeric data." I'll credit you in the adoption of your workaround.

I dont understand why OP needs Column C and D to take into account when there is no use of those.

It still works when I add a dummy column; see screenshot I added

It is working because it has all the conditions, if it doesn't then? Also Column D is empty. Excel will read it as 0

SUMPRODUCT function - Microsoft Support

SUMPRODUCT treats non-numeric array entries as if they were zeros.

So the following works without error checking (please replace , with ; if needed),
=SUMPRODUCT(
IF(I3="",1,A3:A8=I3)
* IF(I4="",1,B3:B8=I4)
* IF(I1="",1,C1:G1=I1)
* IF(I2="",1,C2:G2=I2),
C3:G8)

